# Heterogenous Type Fetching In HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible to have a HashMap that takes a uniform key( say of type 'String' ) but have a value that varies. For Example consider the HashMap **m**.
I want the following functionality:

```
    m.get("UID1"); // This fetches a String value 
    m.get("UID2"); // This fetches another type like a class instance
```

Then depending on the type of value fetched, further processing can be done.

Comment: How about `Map<String, Object>`? You'll have to cast the values after reading, though. How do you want to use/process it?

Comment: you can set `Map<String, Type>`, where `Type` is an Iterface. Then you can add different implementation of it. Or maybe a `Map` is not what you need. Please give us more details and examples of what do you want to do

Comment: @elbraulio "you can set Map<String, Type>, where Type is an Iterface" but then you wouldn't be able to add any of the built-in types as the map values like `String` , `Long`, `Character` etc...

Comment: @Aomine can you give an example where you need that functionality? maybe a `Map` is not the solution

Comment: @elbraulio a `Map` is the solution but it would need to be `Map<String, Object>` as suggested by @ernest_k

Comment: @Aomine if you use `Map<String, Object>` you will need to cast the type every time you use `map.get("some")`. That works but is not the best solution because you are trusting in the cast an it can fail in runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

//Retreive a string:
String myString = (String) m.get("UID1");

//Retreive a variable of any type
MyType variable = (MyType) m.get("UID2");
```

Or if possible, you could set the type of your hashmap to the type you need and if you want a String, you could do toString().

For exemple:

```
HashMap<String, MyObject> m = new HashMap<>();

//Retreive the string representation of your object:
String myString = m.get("UID1").toString();

//Retreive the object:
MyObject object = m.get("UID2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Strings as keys you will lose type safety and there is no way around it. You will simply be giving up all the information the compiler has and you will be forced to provide it yourself manually.

Instead, you can use some kind of wrapper class for the String which also contains type information. This way you can get a reasonable amount of type safety.

Here is an example for the class Foo which wraps a HashMap and provides type safe put and get methods:

```
public class Foo {

static class TypedKey<T> {
    final Class<T> clazz;
    final String id;
    public TypedKey(Class<T> clazz, String id) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof TypedKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id.equals(((TypedKey<?>) obj).id);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}

static final TypedKey<String> STRING_KEY = new TypedKey<>(String.class, "String");
static final TypedKey<Integer> INTEGER_KEY = new TypedKey<>(Integer.class, "Integer");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    foo.put(STRING_KEY, "bar");
    String bar = foo.get(STRING_KEY);

    foo.put(INTEGER_KEY, 42);
    int baz = foo.get(INTEGER_KEY);

    foo.put(STRING_KEY, 42);
}

final Map<TypedKey<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void put(TypedKey<T> key, T value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T get(TypedKey<T> key) {
    return (T) map.get(key);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use classes as keys, not stings. This will give you the opportunity to  do it in a typesafe way, as described by Joshua Bloch as "typesafe heterogenous container":

```
public static class Container {
  private Map<Class<?>, Object> store = new HashMap<>();

  public <T> void put(Class<T> type, T value) {
    store.put(Objects.requireNonNull(type), value);
  }

  public <T> T get(Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(store.get(type));
  }
}
```

You can put a value and retrieve it in a typesafe way like this:

```
Container container = new Container();

container.put(String.class, "test");
container.put(Integer.class, Integer.valueOf(5));

String s = container.get(String.class);
Integer i = container.get(Integer.class);
```

But this will only work, if you have only one value per type.

Comment: Thanks @Donat . Yes it works with one value per type